# Django ListView settting variable to model instance element

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

In my `views.py` class for a ListView I'm trying to add a formula that uses a specific element from an object in the `get_context_data()` method.  Here is what I've tried.

Models.py

```
Class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.FloatField()
    bar = models.FloatField()
```

views.py

```
class MyView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = "my_item_list.html"
    model = MyModel

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=this_object_id)

        var_a = obj['foo']
        var_b = obj['bar']
        result = var_a * var_b

        context = {
            'result': result,
        }

        return context
```

This throws an `object does not support indexing` error.  I've tried several different methods of accessing the specific object element without luck.  I'm not trying to annotate (which is the vast majority of SO Q&A), just use the value from the specified object field.

As a side note, if I pass `obj` into the context data I can easily iterate to the element value in the template - so i know that the `.get()` method is working correctly - it's just the "simple" math in the view I can't get to work.

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757469/django-convert-model-instance-to-dict) (`model_to_dict()`), but it is turning the `obj` into a dictionary - I think this could work, but seems much more wordy than I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use attribute, object is the instance of model class not dict

```
    var_a = obj.foo
    var_b = obj.bar
    result = var_a * var_b
```

and best is create property in the declare of the model:

```
Class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.FloatField()
    bar = models.FloatField()

    @property
    def multiply_fb(self):
        return self.foo * self.bar
```

and in the view:

```
class MyView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = "my_item_list.html"
    model = MyModel

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=this_object_id)
        context = {
            'result': obj.multiply_fb,
        }
        return context
```

Comment: Using the `attribute` for variable assignment was what I was looking for - it worked perfectly.  Thanks again.