# Using Django's to_dict function

Tags: python, json, django

I'm able to successfully serialize my model objects using django serializers, but want a dictionary, not a list with a dictionary in it.  I naturally googled and read other Stack Overflow answers, but I don't understand how to implement the solutions.  This is a basic question, but I'm learning.

I'm trying to send models to Keen.io, and when using Django's serializer, am getting a list with objects, which yields the following error:

```
{u'message': u'An event should be a JSON object of properties.', u'error_code': u'InvalidEventError'}
```

So I'm trying to get a proper JSON object.

Here's my model:

```
class CustomModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    birthday = models.DateField()
```

I've been looking at some of the built in Django options as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925671/convert-django-model-object-to-dict-with-all-of-the-fields-intact#21925671), but I don't understand how to use them, and I'd like to. So if some folks could address a couple of questions:

The function to_dict() seems to be used only for instances? Can it be used for a full Model? When I try, I get an Attribute error. How can I use it to render my model as a dict? Will that get me what I need?

Comment: CustomModel.__dict__ gives you a dict proxy. May be that is what you want ?

Comment: that  doesn't list the values in string form, but in hex. is there a way to pass in the string form?

Comment: There is no straightforward way actually. there is CustomModel._meta.get_fields() which again gives a similar result

Comment: If the serializers give you a list with a dict in it, why don't you just take the dict that's in the list and send that?