# Django Model to Associative Array

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to convert a django models to an associative array using a loop for HttpResponse.

```
class Guest(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mname = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="", blank=True, null=True)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=gender_choices, default="")
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    address = models.TextField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", blank=True, null=True)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="", blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    id_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="", blank=True, null=True)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="", blank=True, null=True)
```

my expected result was like this

```
{ 
    "fname" : "sample",
    "mname" : "sample",
    "lname" : "sample",
    ...
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925671/convert-django-model-object-to-dict-with-all-of-the-fields-intact, though it sounds like you are in need for "django rest framework" which was made for this task (see its serializers)

Answer (score 1):

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(id=pk).values()[0]
```

You will get

```
{ 
    "fname" : "sample",
    "mname" : "sample",
    "lname" : "sample",
    ...
}
```

I discourage the using of `__dict__` because you will get extra fields that you don't care about.

Or you can create `to_dict` method in your models if you want to something more customisable in order to add calculated fields.

```
class Guest(models.Model):
     #fields....


    def get_dict(self):
        return { 
            "fname" : self.fname,
            "mname" : self.mname,
            "lname" : self.lname,
        }
```

use it as it: `instance.get_dict()`

Comment: i've tried the " Guest.objects.get(id=pk).values() " but and exception " 'Guest' object has no attribute 'values' " was returned.

Comment: @KrLontoc Sorry, I updated my answer, its `SomeModel.objects.filter(id=instance.id).values()[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
guest = Guest.objects.get(pk=1)
print guest.__dict__
```