# Communicate AJAX and Django View in template

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Hello I am trying to communicate my view to my ajax script.

> **urls.py**

```
from .views import (
    video_testimonial,
)
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/video_testimonial/$', video_testimonial, name='video_testimonial'),
]
```

So basically it requires an integer in order the url can be access.

e.g  **0/video_testimonial/**

Here's my

> views.py

```
def video_testimonial(request, id):
    testimonial = Testimonial.objects.filter(id=id)

    if request.is_ajax():
        context = {
            'testimonial': testimonial,
        }
        return JsonResponse(context)
    else:
        raise Http404
```

my script (internal script) in my html:

> **presentation.html**

```
function showVideoTestimonial() {
        var id = parseInt($('.carousel-inner a').attr('id'));
        $.ajax({
            url: id +'/video_testimonial/',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.testimonial);
                $('.carousel-inner a').click(function () {
                    console.log(id);
                });
            }
        })
    }
    showVideoTestimonial();
```

> url: id +'/video_testimonial/', am i missing something accessing the url? thanks for responding

**EDIT:**
error shows:
[image]

Comment: can you check your network and tell in more details what is the error? Inspect element in your browser and check network tab, and tell us what is the error? can you check also if you have any error in console?

Comment: i updated my question.

Comment: url: this will add to your current url "id +'/video_testimonial/" so ~> Fail. Url can't catch this

Comment: how do i concatenate the id to the url then

Comment: the error is `return JsonResponse(context)`not url;

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `.filter`, you should use `.get` as it should return one object. The error says that the QuerySet is not Json serializable which is very obvious. What you need is to just convert the object to dict. It can easily be done by doing

`testimonial.__dict__`

Make sure that `testimonial` is a model object not a queryset.

For more details how to convert the object to dict you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/29088221/4117381

Side Note: It is always better to make the json request with the full url. If you are using Django template you can use `{% url 'video_testimonial' id%}`

Comment: you mean, url: {% url ' video_testismonial' id%} ?

Comment: yes but your version is working. The error you are encountering is regarding the serializable object. But `url: {% url ' video_testismonial' id%}` will work just fine if the js is inside .html file