# How do I pass a dictionary from one view to another in Django using session?

Tags: python, django, session

I have used session to pass dict from one view to another. But it shows this error. I want to create multiple templates submit form.

[image]

my **views.py**

```
def view_qr_code(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # here i wanna retrive session data
    context = {
        'code': 'qrcode'
    }
    return render(request, 'add_send_product.html', context)


def send_product_add(request):
    form = SendProductForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            data_dict = instance.__dict__
            print data_dict
            request.session['s'] = data_dict
            return redirect('/qr-code/')

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Form is not valid")

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'headline': 'Delivery Item'
    }
    return render(request, 'add_send_product.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^send-product/add/$', views.send_product_add, name='add_send_product'),
    url(r'^qr-code/$', views.view_qr_code, name='qr_code'),
]
```

Comment: `.__dict__` of a model class will contains some values which is not JSON serializable. So do it like from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925671/convert-django-model-object-to-dict-with-all-of-the-fields-intact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't want to save data in send_product_add() method so you just store request.POST data in your session variable

```
def view_qr_code(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # here i wanna retrive session data
    data_dict = request.session.get('saved')
    del data_dict['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] # middleware is not same here so 
    context = {
        'code': 'qrcode'
    }
    return render(request, 'add_send_product.html', context)


def send_product_add(request):
    form = SendProductForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['saved'] = request.POST
            return redirect('/qr-code/')

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Form is not valid")

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'headline': 'Delivery Item'
    }
    return render(request, 'add_send_product.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't serialize the model instance. Serialize the form's `cleaned_data`.

(I'm not sure what you are doing here, since you never save the instance anyway. If you did, I would say that you should just store the ID of the newly-created instance in the session.)

Comment: I want to save data in the 2nd view if user want otherwise it won't save in db.

Comment: I have 15 items to pass using session. Can i store it one by one with different key in request session?