# Get data from two django models

Tags: django, python-3.x

My models look like this:

```
class UserDevice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT,  null=False)
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
    activation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=False)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    is_owner = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
    is_alerts_enabled = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, null=False)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
    token = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True)
    first_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, null=False)
```

I need to get `device, user, is_alerts_enabled, is_admin, is_owner` from `UserDevice` and `first_name, last_name, token` from `userProfile`. This is what I have so far and it gives me what I need from `userdevice` but I can't figure out how to add the `userprofile` stuff.

```
nonOwners = UserDevice.objects.filter(device=device, is_owner=False)

if nonOwners is None:
    return errormsg('non nonOwners found for this device')

nonOwnersArray=[]

for nonOwner in nonOwners:

    nonOwner_data = model_to_dict(nonOwner,
                               fieldlist=(
                                   'device.serial',
                                   'user.email',
                                   'is_alerts_enabled',
                                   'is_admin',
                                   'is_owner',
                                   ),
                               rename={
                                   'device.serial': 'serial',
                                   'user.email': 'email'})


    nonOwnersArray.append(nonOwner_data)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Django Model object to dict with all of the fields intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925671/convert-django-model-object-to-dict-with-all-of-the-fields-intact)

Comment: No this is not a duplicate.

Comment: The only connection between those models is a third model: `User`. Are you sure you do not want to add a ForeignKey between `UserDevice` and `UserProfile`?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get a dictionary of values is to use [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values).

```
UserDevice.objects.filter(device=device, is_owner=False).values('device', 'user', 'is_alerts_enabled', 'is_admin', 'is_owner')
```

The above line will give you the relevant fields of the `UserDevice` model as dictionary values.

If you add a foreign key to `UserDevice` (here I have changed the `user` field):

```
class UserDevice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.PROTECT,  null=False)
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
    activation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=False)
    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    is_owner = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
    is_alerts_enabled = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, null=False)
```

You may do this:

```
UserDevice.objects.select_related('user').filter(device=device, is_owner=False).values('device', 'user', 'is_alerts_enabled', 'is_admin', 'is_owner', 'user__first_name', 'user__last_name', 'user__token')
```

I have used [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to avoid hitting the database unnecessarily.