# Field name and value in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would like to display something like this in my template:

> **Name**: John
>
> **Age**: 18
>
> **City**: New York

Using, for example, this code:

**views.py**

```
def person_details(request,pk):
   person = get_object_or_404(Person, id=pk)
   return render(request, 'template.html', {'person': person, 'person_fields': person._meta.get_fields()})
```

**template.html**

```
{% for field in person_fields %}        
     <div class="col-4 form-group">            
         <p><strong>{{ field.verbose_name }}:</strong> {{ person[ field.name ]  }}</p>             
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Is this possible in python? I ask because I have a model that have about 20 fields and hard coding the fields in template would be a little hard.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Django's **to-python** queryset serializer.

Just put the following code in your view:

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize( "python", SomeModel.objects.all() )
```

And then in the template:

```
{% for instance in data %}
    {% for field, value in instance.fields.items %}
        {{ field }}: {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Its great advantage is the fact that it handles relation fields.

For the subset of fields try:

```
data = serializers.serialize('python', SomeModel.objects.all(), fields=('name','size'))
```

Comment: Worked for me, thank you so much! I didn't know about this serializers. they will make a lot of other situations in my coding easier. T

Comment: One more question. It's there a way to show the verbose_name of the field? I tried putting {{ field.verbose_name }} but didn't work.

Comment: no you cannot do it like that to display it in template. post it as a question

Answer (score 0):

Django templates are deliberately restricted, such that writing business logic is hard (or close to impossible). One typically performs such logic in the model or view layer.

```
def person_details(request, pk):
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, id=pk)
    person_data = {
       f.verbose_name: getattr(person, f.name, None)
       for f in person._meta.get_fields()
    }
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'person': person, 'person_data': person_data })
```

and then render it with:

```
{% for ky, val in person_data.items %}
     <div class="col-4 form-group">            
         <p><strong>{{ ky }}:</strong> {{ val }}</p>             
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

It is however advisable *not* to do this serialization yourself, but to use other serialization methods like [these listed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29088221/67579).