# why there is like Bunch of backslash in my JSON output

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I m trying to send model data as json using below code

**Views.py**

```
def autocomplete(request):
    model = NewCarModel.objects.only('car_model_new')
    print('model is',model)
   # users_list = list(model)
    posts_serialized = serializers.serialize('json', model)
    print('post is',posts_serialized)

    return JsonResponse(posts_serialized,safe=False)
```

models.py

```
class NewCarModel(models.Model):
    car_model_new = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.car_model_new
```

output:

```
"[{\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 1, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"swift\"}}, {\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 2, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"wagonr\"}}, {\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 3, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"baleno\"}}, {\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 4, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"breeza\"}}, {\"model\": \"core.newcarmodel\", \"pk\": 5, \"fields\": {\"car_model_new\": \"spresso\"}}]"
```

why there is bunch of backslash in my JSON output and how i can remove them and Mozilla Firefox default JSON filter is also not working, neither i am able to extract data from it using java script(as i am able to extract data from some public API so there is no problem with extract code)

edit:

how I m trying to extract data
after parsing JSON into variable myArr

```
const carModelsArr = myArr.data.map((d) => d.fields.car_model_new
```

edit 2:
so solution of not able to extact is  instead of

```
var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

used this:

```
var myArr = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
```

and extract code is able to work

but still, doesn't solve backslash problem and I would like to avoid using DRF if possible

Comment: use `print("[{\"model\":)` and you will no see slashes. It is only information that `"` is inside `" "` and it is not end of string.

Comment: when i parse data in javascript ,they gone but i am unable to extract any data from it

Comment: create minimal working code which show it. Or at least show JavaScript code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think serializer does this to enclose double quote `"` around the dict object while converting them to Json object. Possibly that dict object already have either key or value enclosed with same double quote `"`. Hence that backslash.

To get rid of that you have to use `json.loads` if using **Python** otherwise `JSON.parse` if using **JS**

**Python3:**

```
json.loads(response)
```

**JS:**

```
JSON.parse(data)
```

[image]

## Edit

You are serializing the data twice hence that backslash and you're forced to use `JSON.parse` twice. Since you already serialized the response you can simply use `HttpResponse` or `Response` to return that serialized data.

**Solution-1**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
return HttpResponse(posts_serialized, content_type='application/json')
```

**Solution-2**:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
return Response(posts_serialized, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: i tried JSON.parse(data) and giving same output as yours and tried to extract data but i am unable to extract any of data either its shows nothing or shows undefined

Comment: how you extract?

Comment: after parsing in myArr vaiable```const carModelsArr = myArr.map((d) => d.fields.car_model_new)```

Comment: Does `myArr` holds the correct value? If yes then check the `map` how can be used in the appropriate way.

Comment: actually it's working now, I solve the extract problem by calling var myArr = ```JSON.parse(JSON.parse(this.responseText));``` i have to call parse two times

Comment: Glad to hear that. If my answer helped you in any way, you may accept it.

Comment: plan to do so but I will wait till evening

Comment: You require `JSON.parse` twice because you are serializing the response twice. Replace `return Json...` with `return HttpResponse(posts_serialized, mimetype='application/json')`. Should work

Comment: got error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'

Comment: its should be content_type instead of mimetype

Comment: and its working, can you re-edit your answer with this

Comment: You may try using `Response` instread. `from rest_framework.response import Response`. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/

Comment: as I edit in my question, I would like to avoid DRF if possible and your answer is satisfying

Answer (score 2):

It's because of JsonResponse. As you can see in the documentation od [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) it expects a dictionary and you already created a JSON string. I assume that due to the fact that you said `safe=False` it accepted the string.

I suggest replacing it with the [DRF Response](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/) or parsing it from a Query to a Python dict. (I would prefer the DRF Response option).

For more info, please check out the docs in the links.

Note: I have not run the code myself - it is my assumption.

Comment: As you can see i commented the code where tried to parse it in list first but it causing error, i will look into DRF Response if it give better result or not

Comment: In order to use JsonResponse you need not to serialize, which turns the data into a JSON, but parse it directly to a dict. Like it is said here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925671/convert-django-model-object-to-dict-with-all-of-the-fields-intact

In your case, by running `posts_serialized = serializers.serialize('json', model)` you make it a JSON - which is the more correct way of handling it in my opinion.I would just advise to keep using DRF and return the Response object I suggested.