# How to get custom column from MYSQL table through Django

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to get specific column from DV table based on input from user.

**db** :

```
animal   weight   height

cat        40        20
wolf       100       50
```

first i need to get what animal user wants

```
input1='cat'
```

and then information about the input1 like weight or height

```
input2='weight'

animalwho=Wildlife.objects.get(animal=input1)
```

So if i put `animalwho.weight` it give me 40

But i want to get column based on input2 as input 2 might be height or any other

I tried `animalwho.input2` but it does not work.

Is that possible to get column based on input2?

Would apopreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to convert your object to a dict or get dict directly using `values`.

Many options to convert object to dict see here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925671/convert-django-model-object-to-dict-with-all-of-the-fields-intact/29088221)

Then you can easily

```
animalwho_dict=Wildlife.objects.filter(animal=input1).values()[0]

input2_value = animalwho_dict[input2]
```