# How to Print all values for Single object in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

i am selecting last object from my table using following Code

```
data= MyModel.objects.last()
```

This is Displaying object. i want to display full array of 'data' object.for that i am using Following Code

```
data= MyModel.objects.last().values()
```

However its not Working.How to do that?

Comment: If you have a single object without a queryset: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21925671

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should swap [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) and [**`.last()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#last), since before the `.last()`, you are working with a `Manager` or `QuerySet`, after `.last()` you are working with a `MyModel` *object*:

```
data= MyModel.objects.values().last()
```

That being said, using `.values()` is often *not* a good idea. It erodes the logic layer a model provides. Only in specific cases, like a `GROUP BY` on a certain value it is a good idea to use `.values()`.

Comment: how do you go for printing the data? 
print(data) doesn't work for me