# Queryset to build "pivot table" for the dataset using Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have `CurrencyHistory` model along with the database table which is populated on every `Currency` model update for the historical data.

```
class CurrencyHistory(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    change_rate_date = models.DateTimeField(_("Change Rate Date"), 
                                        auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, 
                                        db_column='change_rate_date')

    code = models.ForeignKey("core.Currency", verbose_name=_("Code"), 
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         related_name='history',
                         db_column='code')

    to_usd_rate = models.DecimalField(_("To USD Rate"), 
                                  max_digits=20, 
                                  decimal_places=6, 
                                  null=True, 
                                  db_column='to_usd_rate')
```

Database structure looks like

```
id | change_rate_date | code | to_usd_rate
 1 | 2021-01-01       | EUR  | 0.123456
 2 | 2021-01-01       | CAD  | 0.987654
 3 | 2021-01-02       | EUR  | 0.123459
 4 | 2021-01-02       | CAD  | 0.987651
```

I need to fetch data using Djnago ORM to have a dictionary to display single row per date with the every currency as columns, like this

| Date | EUR | CAD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 0.123456 | 0.987654 |
| 2021-01-02 | 0.123459 | 0.987651 |

But I have no idea how to correctly do it using Django ORM to make it fast.

> I suppose for loop over the all unique database dates to get dict for
> each data will work in this case but it looks very slow solution that
> will generate thousands of requests.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use serailizers to turn a model instance into a dictionary. Even if your not using a RESTFUL api, serailizers are the best way to get show dictionaries.

All types of ways to serialize data
[Convert Django Model object to dict with all of the fields intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925671/convert-django-model-object-to-dict-with-all-of-the-fields-intact)

For a quick summary of my top favorite methods..

Method 1.

**Model to dict**

```py
from django.forms import model_to_dict

instance = CurrencyHistory(...)
dict_instance = model_to_dict(instance)
```

---

**Method 2**:

Serailizers (this will show the most detail)

of course this implies that you'll need to install DRF

`pip install rest_framework`

**Serializers.py**

```
# import your model
from rest_framework import serializers


class CurrencySerialzier(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    code = serializers.StringRelatedField()  # returns the string repr of the model inst
    class Meta:
        model = CurrencyHistory
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views.py**

```py
from .serializers import CurrencySerializer
...inside your view

currency_inst = CurrencyHistory.objects.get()
serializer = CurrencySerializer(currency_inst)
serializer.data # this returns a mapping of the instance (dictionary)

# here is where you either return a context object and template, or return a DRF Response object
```

Comment: Did you mean `from django.forms.models import model_to_dict`?

Comment: @Gathide I fixed it. `django.forms import model_to_dict`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [django-pivot](https://pypi.org/project/django-pivot/) module. After you `pip install django-pivot`:

```py
from django_pivot.pivot import pivot

pivot_table_dictionary = pivot(CurrencyHistory,
                               'change_rate_date',
                               'code',
                               'to_usd_rate')
```

The default aggregation is `Sum` which will work fine if you only have one entry per date per currency. If the same currency shows up multiple times on a single date, you'll need to choose what number you want to display. The average of to_usd_rate? The max? You can pass the aggregation function to the pivot call.

Alternatively, put `unique_together = [('change_rate_date', 'code')]` in the Meta class of your model to ensure there really is only one value for each date, code pair.