# How to get the model default value after creating new, without call another get?

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to get default value (such as ID of type UUID) after creating a new row.

Here is my model

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table="business"
```

When I create I do this, for example

```
from rest_framework import generics
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

class Create(generics.CreateAPIView):
    def post(self, request)
        inputData = {"name":"abcdef", "created_at": datetime.datetime.now}
        employee = Employee.objects.create(**inputData)    
        return JsonResponse(model_to_dict(employee), safe=False)
```

Here is the response:

```
{
    "name": "abcdef",
    "created_at": "2022-05-24T10:36:39.126",
}
```

So now I dont know what is the ID of the new row I just create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you set `id` as non-editable. At the same time, `model_to_dict` returns a dictionary suitable for passing as a Form's `initial` keyword argument.

You can easily check the source code of `model_to_dict`, and see that fields with such attribute set are skipped. Check this [Convert Django Model object to dict with all of the fields intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925671/convert-django-model-object-to-dict-with-all-of-the-fields-intact) it might be helpfull.