# Django User' object is not iterable or not serializable

Tags: json, django

I am new in Django
I have this function in views.py

```
def edituser(request, id):
    member = User.objects.get(id=id)
    return JsonResponse(member, safe=False)
```

i have the error: Object of type User is not JSON serializable

How can i solve  to return User values to javascript ajax function ?

Comment: If you want a list of one object, use `[x]`, not `list(x)`.  (I don't see _why_ you would want a list in this case though, as it's guaranteed to have one one item...)

Comment: json only knowns about basic data types: integer, string, float, list, dict, etc.  It doesn't know how to convert custom classes.

Comment: you means: member = [User.objects.get(id=id)]  ?
This doesn't work too

Comment: It fixed the "Django User object is not iterable" error, which is all I intended.  (But again, you have not said _why_ you wuld want a list of one item...)

Comment: I don't want a list i am only trying to return the User values

Comment: _I don't want a list_ Then it's quite surprising that you tried to use `list()`...

Comment: ok let's forget the list. How can i return User values and solve the issue of Object of type User is not JSON serializable ?

Comment: Check out this useful answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29088221/4151233

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is here: https://linuxpip.org/object-of-type-is-not-json-serializable/ since the User object IS and/or contains non-serializables values, let's call them "this object contains a thing that have not a Javascript equivalent" check if you have an attribute out of the table in the link provided, to solve this maybe you should filter the "User" object using `json.JSONEncoder`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the attributes that you want to return from the User object, you could construct a dictionary of those specific attributes:

```
def edituser(request, id):
    member = User.objects.get(id=id)
    member_dict = {
        "id": member.id,
        "name": member.name,
        "email": member.email,
        # etc...
    }
    return JsonResponse(member_dict, safe=False)
```